# iOS 6 Map doesn't zoom with MKUserTrackingModeFollow

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location, ios6-maps

While my iOS6 `MKMapView` is in `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` or `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`, zoom gestures (pinch, double-tap, two-finger tap) work sometimes, but not always.

The issue seems to occur when `didUpdateUserLocation:` is called **after** `regionWillChangeAnimated` and **before** `regionDidChangeAnimated`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

To isolate the problems, I've created a Single View Application with an `MKMapView` and a `UIToolbar` (set up in a .xib), to which I'm adding a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`. The `UIViewController` acts as a `<MKMapViewDelegate>`. Here's the complete implementation code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapView, toolbar;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];

    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, nil] animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"regionWillChange >>");
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"<< regionDidChange");
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    NSLog(@"-- didUpdateUserLocation --");
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // required for <MKMapViewDelegate>
}


#pragma mark - etc

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: This issue may or may not be related to other MapKit issues I'm experiencing: [iOS 6 Map problems with MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664092)

Comment: I have the same problem. I've removed everything except 'setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow' and tried using 'animated:NO'. Did you ever find a solution?